# How to transform an NSArray of lat/long coordinates w/format: "("99.9999","99.9999")" into an NSArray of valid CLLocation to use in an MKOverlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocation, mkoverlay

I'm trying to parse an array of `NSStrings` with `lat/long coordinates("99.999999","99.999999")` and then transform it into an `array` of `CLLocations`.

Is there a `NSString` method that would help with this?

I'm pulling these coordinates from an external REST API and then converting the `JSON` into a dictionary first and then an array, that's where I'm stuck.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);


NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

// Show ALL values coming out of NSJSONSerialization
for(id key in jsonResult) {

    id value = [jsonResult objectForKey:key];

    NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
    NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

    NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
    NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
}

    NSArray *jsonCoordinates =[jsonResult objectForKey:@"latlng"];


for (id key in jsonCoordinates) {

    //id value = [jsonCoordinates objectForKey:key];

    NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
    //NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

    NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
    //NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
}


}
```

Log output:

2013-04-29 22:23:44.894 RideInfo[9271:c07] key: (
    "37.473497",
    "-122.213878"
)
2013-04-29 22:23:44.894 RideInfo[9271:c07] key: (
    "37.47346",
    "-122.213538"
)

Comment: Are you sure that the string `("99.999", "99.999")` isn't the description of an `NSArray` you already have? If it is, as I suspect, then `CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { [array[0] doubleValue], [array[1] doubleValue] };`

Comment: I updated my post with a couple of lines of NSLog output, each element of the array corresponds to a set of lat/long coordinates. I need to go through each pair and turn them into CLLocation.

Comment: I've added an answer. By the way, why do you assume the values are strings? Most probably they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The values are not strings (I don't understand why you assume they are). They are `NSArray` objects. Those arrays presumablly contain either `NSNumber` or `NSString` objects (it's impossible to tell which one without seeing the actual JSON you receive), so they respond to the `doubleValue` message which gives their value as a `double`, which is suited for the initialization of a `CLLocation` object:

```
NSMutableArray *locs = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in jsonResult) {
    NSArray *pair = jsonResult[key];
    double lat = [pair[0] doubleValue];
    double lon = [pair[1] doubleValue];
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
    [locs addObject:loc];
    // if non-ARC:
    [loc release];
}
```

Here `locs` will contain an array of `CLLocation` objects.

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to make it work but I had to make some adjustments:
    
    NSArray *jsonCoordinates =[jsonResult objectForKey:@"latlng"];
 
    NSMutableArray *routeCoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
    for (id index in jsonCoordinates) {
        //NSArray *pair = [jsonCoordinates objectAtIndex:index];
        double lat = [index[0] doubleValue];
        double lon = [index[1] doubleValue];
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
        [routeCoords addObject:loc];
        
    }